# Mimic table in MySQL (view or stored function)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view, stored-functions

Currently I have User structure which is defined in two tables:
User (id, name) and UserParams (user_id, param, value)
So, current data looks in a way below:

```
User:
id, name
1, "John"
2, "Bob"

UserParams:
user_id, param, value
1, "Address", "Kilmainham str"
1, "Phone", "+12345678"
```

I want to refactor database so User will have explicit columns address, phone and etc:

```
New User structure:
id, name, address, phone
1, "John", "Kilmainham str", "+12345678"
2, "Bob", "Orc's cave", "just speak up"
```

The bad thing, the database has many stored procedures which will be very difficult to refactor in a single streak. So, I want to have a view or stored function which will mimic old "UserParams" behavior.

```
SELECT * FROM UserParams WHERE user_id=1;
1, "Address", "Kilmainham str"
1, "Phone", "+12345678"
```

Is it any way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW UserParams  (user_id, param, value)
AS SELECT  id,  "Address"  , address 
FROM New_User
UNION 
SELECT id, "Phone", phone
FROM New_User
```